# C++ Wrapper for threadx RTOS?

Tags: c++, wrapper

Is there any authentic,efficient and robust C++ wrapper for Threadx RTOS which can be used out of the box ?
My embedded software application is written  in C++ but now I want to create a RTOS wrapper to use ThreadX RTOS. Any idea would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[The official ThreadX tools list](https://rtos.com/partners/tools/) has several C++ compilers for ThreadX, such as Atollic TrueStudio and IAR Systems Embedded Workbench. You might find a good starting point there.

Comment: We are using IAR Embedded Workbench. It doesn't give out of the box solution .